# Cygwin and Windows path conflict; using both Windows and cygwin Python

Tags: python, svn, mercurial, cygwin

I've installed cygwin on Windows XP. Mercurial on cygwin stopped working after I installed some software on Windows. The symptom can be simplified to python not being able to locate modules in its library:

```
>>> import os
Traceback (most recent call last):
  file "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named os
```

One of the pieces of software I installed in Windows (subversion) uses python so now Windows has its own Python installation. Don't ask why I wish to use mercurial under cygwin and subversion under Windows; suffice to say I do, but that's beside the point. It seems cygwin tries to use the Windows python instead of its own, or at least that's what I think is happening. If that's not the cause, please enlighten me. Anyway...

$ find /cygdrive/c -name os.py
   /cygdrive/c/csvn/Python25/Lib/os.py
   /cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/python2.6/os.py

echo $PATH confirms that /cygdrive/c/csvn/Python25 is before /usr/lib/python2.6. I'm no cygwin wiz, but from what I can tell /etc/profile adds the Windows path to cygwin's $PATH, and I don't know how to keep it from doing so. As a workaround I modified .profile to explicitly set PATH, excluding those paths from Windows. But, the problem remains:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/python2.6
$ hg
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hg", line 10, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os

$ ls /usr/lib/python2.6/os.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py
```

It looks like the path conflict has not actually been resolved, because when I issue the above "find" command again I get the same results, with /cygdrive/c/csvn/Python25/Lib/os.py showing up first. In theory there may be some other reason python isn't working on cygwin, but not being able to control my PATH would still be a problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: My colleague had the same problem. Additional information is, that `sys.path` contains bogus content. Entries starting with `C/csvn/` and `C/Lib` and no correct entries. Now the default sys.path is supposed to be hardcoded in the binary, so it has to be finding some wrong .dlls or reading something wrong from registry (but cygwin apps are not supposed to read those). Unfortunately I don't know what to do about that (colleague fixed it by uninstalling the collabnet subversion client).

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately my colleague who also had the problem already uninstalled the csvn thing, so I can't check. But reading the [doc](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.4/inst/search-path.html) suggests the culpable variable might be `$PYTHONHOME`. Check whether it's set and try unsetting it!

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. $PYTHONHOME was set to the csvn Python which was causing me much confusion on a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solutions found in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122924/bash-cygwin-path-do-i-really-have-to-reboot-to-alter-path)? Seems like a similar problem.

Comment: That looked promising, but no. Thank you for locating that; I tried to dig up related posts but that didn't show up for me. I tried modifying /etc/profile to remove ${PATH} from PATH and then rebooted, and "echo $PATH" shows no Windows paths, but cygwin still looks in those windows paths. When I try to run hg, cygwin gives this warning: "MS-DOS style path detected: \csvn\Python25\/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload"

Comment: Adding to that comment, python still complains that it can't import os. The "find" command also lists the Windows os.py first. I don't know why cygwin insists on using Windows PATH, while "echo $PATH" doesn't show it. It doesn't seem rebooting made any difference.

Comment: Hmm, did you check your PYTHONPATH env. variable? Is it pointing to the right place in Cyg?

Comment: Good thought. It turns out PYTHONPATH wasn't set. Setting it *did* get past the problem of importing os. Unfortunately now it complains that it can't find a module called _functools. I do have /lib/python2.6/functools.py. I tried adding /lib/python2.6 to PATH but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: On further searching, there's also /usr/lib/python2.6/functools.py... same place as that pesky os.py, which it *can* find. Odd.

Comment: PYTHONPATH is not supposed to be set. The python binary has the system directories compiled in and appends them to whatever is in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: As for PATH, cygwin is starting correct python binary, because it prints the version banner matching the cygwin build. But that binary still loads some components from the other installation.